# Accordion in angularjs change is-open value issue

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, accordion

I am trying to open accordion when i click a button, but value of is-open doesn't seem to change in ui after you open / close accordion by your self. I think that this issue is because accordion create a new scope and don't see the changes from my controller. I make a simple example where i have two accordions first witch is open at first and second closed accordion. To see what i mean close first accordion and click at button. You can see in console that the value in is-open param changed but in ui is steal false and accordion closed. Any ideas?

http://plnkr.co/edit/VEIqRfyrP6CbD0j7X4OK?p=preview'>

Comment: Open your console (ctrl + shift + j for Chrome). It prints true...

Comment: Yes  i know that my issue is that accordion doesn't open.

Comment: You don't have secondIsOpen model in your controller. (you don't change it's value): ill provide answer in a minute

Comment: I know that too i just want to open first accordion when you click in open accordion button.

Comment: Then just set firstIsOpen initial value to false;
It's already open when you start your program.

Answer (score 0):

<strike>[Here is a solution](http://plnkr.co/edit/lpRzq8lM6B7kA4rOZH4O?p=preview). You didn't have model `secondIsOpen`</strike>
Your firstIsOpen is set to true at the beginning... that's why accordion doesn't open (it's already open). Set it to false and it should solve your problem.
[Here it is with toggle button](http://plnkr.co/edit/kMFnB8mzRgJ9FPCqg1mL?p=preview)

Comment: I don't want to open one and close the other accordion i want to change the value of firstIsOpen throw controller.

Comment: You have another plunker link. I think that's what you're looking for. If not, I can't help you but recommend to learn how to use debugger.

Comment: Please read what i am saying. If you close first accordion and after that click button accordion doesn't open. I can't change value of firstIsOpen in ui

Comment: I already provided another plunker that does what you are asking for. Check the answer again. At the end there is a link with a toggle button that shows the accordion when you first click the button, then hides it after another click, etc...

Comment: Yes i see that but it doesn't work either. Open and close first accordion and after that click button First accordion doesn't open

Comment: Yes but you didn't do what i said early. Before click button open and close accordion First. Don't open it with button at first